# Dynamically linking SQLCipher on OS X with C++

Tags: c++, macos, dynamic, compiler-errors, dynamic-linking

I originally wanted to compile SQLCipher statically since it seems like it is easier to link up, but I have been unsuccessful at that. The only place I can find that discusses compiling SQLCipher on OS X is [this blog post](http://vinceyuan.blogspot.tw/2013/07/build-sqlcipher-on-mac-os-x.html), but even he was not able to get the static compiling to work.

I was able to get the dynamic compiling working for the SQLCipher and I am able to use the sqlcipher command line program as mentioned in the blog, but now I want to use sqlcipher in a compiled C++ program. I have never dealt directly with dynamic compiling in the command line so I am a bit lost.

It looks like it produces a libtool file libsqlcipher.la so I am wondering how I should import it in C++ `#include "libsqlcipher.h"`? Looking around at tutorials for libtool they mostly mention how to compile it but I have not found any simple examples of how to link it.

I attempted something like this based on what I saw but I got a couple of errors:

```
libtool g++ -o test EncryptDatabases.cpp sqlcipher/libsqlcipher.la
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't open file: g++ (No such file or directory)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: EncryptDatabases.cpp is not an object file (not allowed in a library)
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: sqlcipher/libsqlcipher.la is not an object file (not allowed in a library)
```

Comment: do you have g++ installed?

Comment: Yes, I can compile c++ programs just fine with g++. I've tried another command `g++ EncryptDatabases.cpp -ldl -o test`, looks like it follows the include to the correct path of the dynamic library but maybe I am linking the wrong thing.

Comment: There is no `libsqlcipher.h` only a `libsqlcipher.la` file. But including that doesn't work either.

Comment: I was able to compile sqlcipher statically. There is only one `.o` file present which is `sqlite3.o` but it says that there are undefined symbols when I compile it together `g++ EncryptDatabases.cpp sqlcipher/sqlite3.o -o test`, maybe it still needs to link some things dynamically? I can use sqlcipher just fine in iPhone but they have an easy to follow guide for that.  I'll probably cross post this on the google group SQLCipher Users.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer yes, but too long for a comment.

As far as I remember first libtool should be explicitly told to compile source file into a "library object":

```
libtool --mode=compile g++ -c EncryptDatabases.cpp -o EncryptDatabases.lo
```

then it should link the binary:

```
libtool --mode=link g++ -o test EncryptDatabases.lo sqlcipher/libsqlcipher.la
```

See the [docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Invoking-libtool.html)

Comment: Hmm, maybe there is something different about libtools on mac because I get this: error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: unknown option character `-' in: --mode=compile

Comment: Yes, I've checked MacOS X folks made their own Lunapark, exactly as Bender suggested. I'd like to ask if it's crucial for you to use `libtool` to make a shared library.

Comment: I managed to get it working with the static compiled version: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlcipher/DgWSklNTN-4